# Synchronization of Video frame and Virtual object

Tags: vuforia

I have developed an AR app where it augments virtual object onto the marker, and its frame rate is somewhere between **28-30 fps**.

I want to know how Vuforia handles its synchronization (binding of video frame and virtual object) so quickly that if I move the camera, virtual image will also move instantly. Does this depend on the efficiency (speed) of tracking algorithm or does Vuforia have separate algorithm to achieve this synchronization task.

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally it depends on your Image ofcourse. When you upload the image onto the TargetManager it gives you a star rating. So that's definitely a factor.

But then again, they do have an algorithm which is quite well hidden from the view of the public so, that's all you can get for this question type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read that SLAM performs similar task. Does Vuforia use SLAM algorithm?

Comment: It's really hard to tell. You could probably post this on the Vuforia forum and see if a Moderator replies. This is like asking Google for it's Search Engine algorithm lol.

Comment: Hope you get your answer :) And please share it here as well.